# Button Click in Fragment, Start AsyncTask with Indeterminate ProgressDialog, No Valid Context Available

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialog

Basically, I have built over the default new Activity UI offered by Eclipse and Android Development Tools with the scrollable tabs and swipe.

It is `Fragment` based.

I am trying to inflate a view inside the fragment, attach a button click listener in this view which will initiate an AsyncTask, which will in turn display a progress dialog in its `onPostExecute` method.

Here's some code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, container, false);

            Button bProcess= (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bJustParked);
            bProcess.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    new JustParkedGetLocation().execute();
                }

            });

            // Modify views in fragment below

            return rootView;
        }
```

Obviously, `JustParkedGetLocation` extends AsyncTask and is a subclass of the class which holds the `onCreateView` method above. However, if I want to create a dialog in `JustParkedGetLocation->onPreExecute()`, e.g.:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setIndeterminate(true);
    progress.setTitle("Getting location");
    progress.show();
    super.onPreExecute();
}
```

...the parameter for the `ProgressDialog` constructor is not correct, since the class that holds the `onCreateView` method is static (the class that extends `Fragment`) by default. Resulting in the following error:

```
The constructor ProgressDialog(MainActivity.ExtendedFragment.JustParkedGetLocation) is undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the constructor a reference to the activity context:

```
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
```

Comment: I've tried passing `MainActivity.this`, but I get the following error: `No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope`, probably due to the fact that the class that extends `Fragment` is static and the activity extending class is not. I've tried moving the AsyncTask extending class to be a direct child of the Activity class, but then I again, I can't call it from the Fragment extending class.

Comment: Can you call getActivity() from your fragment? Static class might mess this up as well...

Comment: Yep. `getActivity()` fixed it. Can you include it in your original answer so I can accept it?